# htaccess - make url path act as query string

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, query-string

absolute noob here. I have dynamic website with the following query string:

`https://example.com/?color=blue`

My goal is to mask and convert this query string after ?color= into a path based on the parameter like so:

`https://example.com/blue`

So if I type into browser `https://example.com/blue` then content of `https://example.com/?color=blue` will be displayed while URL remains `https://example.com/blue`

I am not looking for redirect. I think I need internal rewrite but I am not really sure if this is correct term.

I already tried many solutions from stackoverflow and I spent hours on google but none of those solutions fits my site as I don't have any index.php file which everyone is using in htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds pretty straight forward:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?(\w+)$ /?color=$1 [END]
```

Or something like that:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^/?(\w+)$ /?color=$1 [L]
```

However since you write that you "tried many solutions" (which you did not share with us) and "spent hours on google" (instead of looking into the documentation of the tool you use) but that still "none of those solutions fits your site" (which you told us nothing about) I have to assume that your actual issue is something else. I cannot answer to that however, since you did not tell us what your *actual* issue is ...

*(note: i am *not* trying to mock you here, I only try to point out *why* it is impossible to give a better answer to your vague question ...)*

One specific question: if your site does *not* have an `index.php` router (or something similar), then how should the final, rewritten URL `/?color=blue` get processed?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am sorry, let me explain it better.

My site is only index.html file with javascript code which grabs url query string and put it into page titles. 

For example when I go to url „https://example.com/?color=blue“ then title of this page is „My favorite color is blue“. When I go to „https://example.com/?color=red“ then title of this page is „My favorite color is red“. 

Your htaccess code does what I need but now javascript code doesn’t see query string in url so it doesn’t put query string into html titles. Is there any way how to handle this please?

Comment: Ah, ok, so you actually _do_ have a router, it is the javascript logic on the client side. OK, got that. So why can't you then use any of the available solutions? They should work. Just as my suggestion above definitely works.

Comment: I cannot tell you why your javascipt logic does not "see" the query string. _Because you forgot to post your javascript logic ..._ But most likely that is because that information is never sent to the browser if you perform a _server side internal redirection_ , which is what you asked for...

Comment: But if you have a client side logic that evaluates the requested URL, then why can't you simply evaluate the URL _without any server side rewriting logic_ ?

Comment: Well I can’t use it because I have no idea what and how.. I’m not coder, I am basically just using various scripts from here.. php, html and javascript are easy to edit even for noobs but htaccess rules are out of my league.

Comment: My javascript to grab query string from url looks like this:

`if(window.location.search){
  const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  $(‚.color‘).text(urlParams.get(‚color‘));
}`

In html I simply place `<span class="color">Color here</span>` where I want to display desired url query.

Comment: If you say that javascript is so easy to edit, then why can't you change that javascript such that it grabs the path instead of the query string? Should be trivial then?

Comment: I just tried to replace `window.location.search` with `window.location.pathname` but it doesn't work, no idea why.. it completely removes content of the span `<span class="color">Color</span>` from site so title on website is just "My favorite color is"

Comment: Well, there is no "color" in the _path_ of the URL, is there? So how do you expect `urlParams.get(‚color‘)` to work then?

Comment: I got your point.. I tried `urlParams.get('window.location.pathname')` then `urlParams.get('urlParams')` and also `urlParams.get('URLSearchParams')` but nothing.. no idea what else I could paste there. I guess I have to define somehow content of window.location.pathname but how and where

Comment: Sorry, but it gets more and more clear that you actually have no idea what you are doing. Don't get that wrong, again I am not trying to mock you, I am just stating what I see. There is little sense in trying around some words. You need to start learning how to program if you want to program. You need to stop copying script snippets from somewhere when you don't understand what those actually do. That is not a way to succeed in software. Sorry.

Comment: Please read a bit about asking here on SO works. Please understand that we are not here to do your work for you, to solve your task for you. We are here to offer help when you get stuck with a specific detail of what you are trying to implement. But for that you must be able to implement something yourself. The Q&A style used here is not suited to teach you programming. Please start learning to program how everyone else does. Just picking a few scripts and trying to change a few expressions is _not_ the right approach. Sorry.